# Question on usage of words

Tags: differences, prepositions, terminology

I heard this phrase long ago. I have always wondered the obvious WHY?
Why is it that we park in our driveway
and drive on a parkway?

Comment: What is the question here? Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: This is completely different question from the other. Both deserve an answer.

Comment: It strikes me that this is exactly the same question, or at least, the answers there answer this question too. If they don't, please edit this question, referencing the other, to say why they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that roads are usually paved and drives are often not. You can't park *on* mud. You have to park *in* it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two meanings of the word park:

1. a large public garden or area of land used for recreation.
2. bring (a vehicle that one is driving) to a halt and leave it temporarily

Parkway refers to the former.  It is defined as an open landscaped highway.